# How to access a record type element that is passed to a function that is in another file in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

In my exploration of learning `OCaml` I am not understanding how to access the value stored in a record type that is being passed to a function that is in another file.

My Current code:

`main.ml` file

```
(* Declaring a token record type*)
type 'a tokens = { 
                   error_tok : 'a;
                   id_tok    : 'a;          
                 }

let main_fun () =                   
                let token = { 
                              error_tok = -1;
                              id_tok    =  0;           
                            } in

               let tok = Rdp.rdp token in
                         print_int tok;

;;

main_fun ();
```

`rdp.ml` file

```
let rdp token = print_string "In RDP function: \n";                  
                print_int token.error_tok;
                0;
```

I am compiling using `ocamlbuild main.native` and getting the compile error of `Unbound record field error_tok`. How would I access the value stored in the passed in record type of `token.error_tok` in my `rdp.ml` file.?

In essence I am trying to treat the record type like an `enum`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there is a dependency cycle between your two modules (Main depends on Rdp for the rdp function, Rdp depends on Main for the type). An easy solution for that is to move the `token` type to `Rdp`. This will move the type error to when you're compiling main.ml since it won't know about the fields when declaring `token`.

Then, there are 3 approaches to bring your record type (and fields) in scope:

#### Open (local or global)

```
let main_fun () =
  let open Rdp in
  let token = {
    error_tok = -1;
    id_tok    =  0;
  }
in
(* ... *)
```

#### Qualify a field

```
let main_fun () =
  let token = {
    Rdp.error_tok = -1;
    id_tok = 0;
  }
in
(* ... *)
```

#### Annotate the record value

```
let main_fun () =
  let token : int Rdp.t = { (* or just : _ Rdp.t *)
    error_tok = -1;
    id_tok    =  0;
  }
in
(* ... *)
```

Comment: In the last case, you can just say `let token : _ Rdp.t` and the `int` will be inferred.

Answer (score 1):

The actual question has been answered already.

> In essence I am trying to treat the record type like an `enum`.

That does not seem to go very well. When compared to C, record types are more akin to `struct`. For `enum` I would recommend variants with constant constructors like so:

```
type token =
  | Error_tok
  | Id_tok
```

This does not assign integer values for the different values of `token` (at least not visibly). Usually that is sufficient, though. You can test equality of values. And you can do the equivalent of `switch` with pattern matching. You can also compare values with `<`, but be warned that the actual order is unspecified (although apparently it seems to be the order you would assume, that is `Error_tok < Id_tok`). If you still need to assign integer values, you can easily do that with a function

```
let token_value = function
  | Error_tok -> -1
  | Id_tok -> 0
```